# RMW_IMPLEMENTATION issue after IP address change

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, dds

I'm running ROS2 Humble on a mobile Robot using a RPI4, headless.
This is my set-up:

1. mobile Robot using ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu 22.04.2
2. laptop for development and remote control
   a) aarch64 compiling inside a docker on main laptop (is faster than on rpi)

This has always worked great and presented no issues, just a hassle moving files after compiling from DEV->BOT

Recently I have set-up a new Wireless AP, also 5.8GHz, but instead of 192.168.68.1/24 I am now in the 192.168.1.1/24 subnet.

I can ssh into the rpi, everything is great. Except when I start a ROS node I'm no longer able to see the topics broadcasted on my development machine (laptop).

Both rpi and laptop use:
Ubuntu 22.04.2
RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_DISTRO=humble

can ping each other, ufw is configured and I also tried with ufw disabled.
Here is the ufw config, enabled on both machines:
To                         Action      From

---

49152/udp                  ALLOW       192.168.68.0/24
49152/udp                  ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
22/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.68.0/24
22/tcp                     ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24

I just can't see the topics / services any more.
Given the fact the rpi is headless, I can not use rqt_graph on remote, only on local (my dev laptop) but that is not helpful.

And yes, I have sourced the setup.bash and used the same packages on both machines.

```
echo $ROS_DOMAIN_ID
remote: 0
local:  0
```

And then checked RMW

```
echo $RMW_IMPLEMENTATION
remote: rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
local:  rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
```

I also checked multicast:
Test1 (Fail)
remote machine term1: ros2 multicast receive
remote machine term2: ros2 multicast send

added ufw rule on both local/remote:

```
sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 192.168.1.0/24
sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 192.168.1.0/24
```

Test2 (Pass)
remote machine term1: ros2 multicast receive
remote machine term2: ros2 multicast send

Test3 (Fail)
local computer: ros2 multicast receive
remote machine: ros2 multicast send

Any idea what I'm missing? Ought to be something simple